# How to sum row values base on dynamic conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to get the sum of each colum [Gliders, Helicopters, Jet engines, Piston engines, Turbo-propellers] for every state each year. So at the end I will get for each REF_DATE I will get only one row for each different state.

Ex: For REF_DATE=2012 if there are 23 states I will get 23 rows with the same REF_DATE (2012), and so on for each REF_DATE.

The condition should be something like:

```
if((REF_DATE==REF_DATE)&&(State==State)):
  sum(Gliders)
  sum(Helicopters)
  sum(...)
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

As @MattPitkin pointed, tt works fine with groupby, the answer was:

```
df_states = df_ap.groupby(['REF_DATE', 'State']).sum()
```

[image]

Comment: for some reason your image isn't visible.

Comment: See the pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method, e.g., `df.groupby(["State", "REF_DATE"]).sum()`

Comment: Thanks @MattPitkin It worked just fine with groupby, the answer was:     df_states = df_ap.groupby(['REF_DATE', 'State']).sum()